# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactCurrentDispatcher$2.current')

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I have had an error appear with some of my recent projects. After a few days of working on a project, this error will appear when viewing the app in the browser:

```
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactCurrentDispatcher$2.current') pushDispatcher node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22582
```

```
  22579 | }
  22580 | 
  22581 | function pushDispatcher() {
> 22582 |   var prevDispatcher = ReactCurrentDispatcher$2.current;
  22583 |   ReactCurrentDispatcher$2.current = ContextOnlyDispatcher;
  22584 | 
  22585 |   if (prevDispatcher === null) {
```

It should be noted that:

- I made sure to upgrade Yarn using `yarn upgrade`.
- This error will still appear even if the app is stripped down to its bare bones.
- If I copy the files over to a new Create React App, the project will work just fine.

---

Here is the file structure:

```bash
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ public/
│  ├─ index.html
├─ src/
│  ├─ App.js
│  ├─ index.js
├─ package.json
├─ yarn.lock
```

And here are the project files:

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return <div className="App">My app</div>;
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "neovrnaz <neovrnaz@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-devtools": "^4.10.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Packages in Yarn follow [Semantic Versioning](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-versions/). By installing packages with the default `yarn add <package-name>`, you are also giving it a [Caret Range](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-versions/#toc-caret-ranges), which is going to affect how upgrading packages work.

Running `yarn upgrade` without any flags *won't* *usually* update anything in `package.json`.

Use `yarn upgrade --latest` if you're are trying to update everything in package.json.